# Catch error on Swift and show it on View Controller with an alert

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I am developing an application for IOS with Swift, and at some point run the line:

```
let myURLString = "http://FILE URL"
var myHTMLString:NSString = ""
if let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString) {
    var error: NSError?
    myHTMLString = NSString(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)!

    if let error = error {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        println("Error : \(error)")
    }
    else {
        println("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
    }
}
else {
    println("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
}
return myHTMLString as String
```

This returns a String.

If the device (or the Mac while working with XCode) do not have Internet, the application fails because:

```
        myHTMLString = NSString(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)!
```

is null (nil)

My question is: How can I catch this error, execution continues, and display an error message in the View Controller?

Comment: BTW, I would advise against using `NSString` with `contentsOfURL`. That's a synchronous call. If you do this at an inopportune point in time (e.g. when the server is sluggish, over slow network, etc.), you can get adverse behavior in your app. It's much better to use `NSURLSession.sharedSession.dataTaskWithURL(...)`, which is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Return myHTMLString as a String? optional instead of the String. Once the calling application gets back the myHTMLString variable, check for nil

```
    if let htmlString = myHTMLString{
         // HTML String returned by function isnt nil
    }
    else {
         // HTML String returned by function is nil. Handle the error
    }
```

Comment: Valueof optional type "NSString?" not unwrapped, did you mean to use "!" or "?". XCode corrects me with ``return (myHTMLString as NSString?)!`` and it happens the same as before. I wonder how to display an error in a View Controller without running it from a button. If you can clarify this, I will give your answer as valid :)

Comment: Why are you doing return (myHTMLString as NSString?)!  ... Remove the last ! and update your func signature to be func xFunc() -> String? { var myHTMLString: String? //do your processing and return myHTMLString}

Comment: Done. Now, How I can create an alert in the view controller? I can do it from a button, but not from an event.

Comment: Could you paste the exact error message/image to the question? Also what does your view controller do with the myHTMLString. Unless I have that code, I cant really give you insights

Comment: I have no error. I simply want to create an alert (pop up) in the view controller.

With myHTMLString I get a String that I parse for information and create objects with this information. If myHTMLString is null, no information that parse, and therefore should inform users and create objects with empty values

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/ has the code for creating a alert view controller

Comment: I see that article before. I need to call that pop up from an event, not from a button.

Comment: You can always create an alert view controller either inside from a button or inside the event handler. Just reuse the code from the link to create a alert view controller